# Change path to the package.json

Tags: npm, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, clean-architecture

I have next structure of solution and now when I try to run npm install on specific project where I should you npm packages I'm getting error.
[image]
How I can manage path so when I run npm install to be run correctly ?
Here is structure of my soultion:
[image: al]

Comment: you should run `npm install` being on the respecting path, no?

Comment: `npm install` needs to be run while the current folder is the one containing the relevant `package.json`.

Comment: I setup as startup project WebAngularSPA, on that project I run package manager console and run npm install, and I'm getting an error like on first screen

Comment: You can change directory in the package manager console. (One might suggest the NPM Task Runner extension which integrates into the task runner of VS, and includes direct support for NPM commands.... OTOH I just run most of these things from a console outside VS.)